# WP8 App Not correctly reading from isolated storage

Tags: c#, wpf, class, windows-phone-8, longlistselector

I currently have this code.

This is the code I actually use to read the file:

```
public ObservableCollection<Esame> rigaEsame = new ObservableCollection<Esame>();
    private void ReadFile()
            {
                Esami.ItemsSource = rigaEsame;
                IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
                IsolatedStorageFileStream fileStream = myIsolatedStorage.OpenFile("exams.txt", FileMode.OpenOrCreate, FileAccess.Read);
                string tmp;
                string tmp2;
                using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(fileStream))
                {
                    while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                    {
                        tmp = reader.ReadLine();
                        tmp2 = reader.ReadLine();
                        rigaEsame.Insert(0, new Esame(tmp,tmp2));
                        Debug.WriteLine(tmp);
                    }
                }
            }
```

This code is the one I use to write to the file:

```
private void InsertEntry_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            IsolatedStorageFile myIsolatedStorage = IsolatedStorageFile.GetUserStoreForApplication();
            using (StreamWriter writeFile = new StreamWriter(new IsolatedStorageFileStream("exams.txt", FileMode.Append, FileAccess.Write, myIsolatedStorage)))
            {
                writeFile.WriteLine(Subject.Text);
                writeFile.WriteLine(Date.Text);
                writeFile.Close();
            }
            NavigationService.Navigate(new Uri("/Views/MainPage.xaml",UriKind.Relative));
        }
```

and this is the class file:

```
public class Esame
    {
        public string nomeEsame { get; set; }
        public string descrizioneEsame { get; set; }
        public string Name
        {
            get { return nomeEsame; }
            set { nomeEsame = value; }
        }

        public Esame(string esame, string descrizione)
          {
              nomeEsame = esame;
              descrizioneEsame = descrizione;
          }
    }
```

I am currently able to write the text from the TextBlock "Subject" and place it into my "Esami" LongListSelector. Still, I am currently unable to correctly read/write the second text string, coming from the TextBlock named "Date".

How may I do that? I suppose there is something wrong with the class itself or the way I use it when putting it into my LongListSelector list item.

How may i fix that?

Comment: Unlike forum sites, we don't use "Thanks", or "Any help appreciated", or signatures on [so]. See "[Should 'Hi', 'thanks,' taglines, and salutations be removed from posts?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2950/should-hi-thanks-taglines-and-salutations-be-removed-from-posts).

Comment: what did you mean exactly by "*unable to correctly read/write the second text string, coming from the TextBlock named "Date"*"? how you know you're unable to do so.

Comment: debug your application and narrow down scope of code that possibly cause the problem (at which line of code it begin to produce unexpected result)